# I can log into my sql server using php myadmin, but cant login using php

Tags: php, mysql, node.js

I have a database with a username, and password. The username is zerk2. I created this user and granted it all permissions known to man. I can use the php my admin panel to physically login to the server and it works every time. However, when I try to use php to log in, or node.js it tells me it cannot connect and gives me the following errors:

```js
NODE JS Error:

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1054:14)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/rbd/pnpm-volume/2b16f76e-5470-449f-9885-fd3654098407/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/rbd/pnpm-volume/2b16f76e-5470-449f-9885-fd3654098407/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (/rbd/pnpm-volume/2b16f76e-5470-449f-9885-fd3654098407/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/connection.js:10:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:759:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:770:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:555:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:826:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
    
NODE JS Code:

const mysql = require('mysql');

const con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "zerk2",
  password: "***",
  database: "***",
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
});
```

```html
PHP Error:

Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): ProxySQL Error: Access denied for user 'zerk2'@'2a02:4780:bad:f00d::7' (using password: YES) in /storage/ssd2/616/14109616/public_html/index.php on line 2
Connection Failed!

PHP Code:
// Note. The stars are there for privacy. However I am certain i have the correct order. Host, username, password, db name
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "zerk2", "***", "***") or die("Connection Failed!");
echo "Connection success!";
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like a total idiot. But the reason it was not working, is because apparently. The web browser FireFox has a sort of built in VPN. That it routes all of your request traffic into. If anyone gets this error, disable aly sort of Proxy, or VPN you might have enabled on your computer or browser.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue is the host `'zerk2'@'2a02:4780:bad:f00d::7'`. You maybe on the same machine but your php and node running from different servers and looks like your node is running via a proxy. php could be running from apache and nodejs from another http server. Not sure how you have set up the server. To fix this you have to modify or create a mysql user with host set to `%` to allow access from any host.

**UPDATES:**

It's failing to connect to mysql server `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306` for NodeJS. Try to use server's ip address or domain as host instead of `localhost` and see if that works for you. PHP looks like it connects but the user don't have access could be the password or the user can't access it from host `2a02:4780:bad:f00d::7` that's why you'll need a mysql user with host `%`. Also note it will not work if you have two users with that same name and one's host is not `%`.

Comment: So, the php is ran on 000webhost. So it is an http server. However, I created an account named zerk, with the host set to % like you said, and yet it still gives me the same error when I run the php code with the new credentials. The database itself is ran from my computer using wampserver. But this error happens when I try to connect to virtually any database on the planet using php or nodejs

Comment: i hate to say it, but it still does not work. im logging in with root this time, and the password is blank, and its set to % to allow access from all hosts. It still doesnt work. https://i.imgur.com/9IAhPaE.png this is from my wamp server. I can type localhost into my browser, and log in using the php myadmin panel perfectly fine. And if what you said is true, that all hosts can access it, i have no idea whats wrong. Ive never had an issue like this in the entire decade ive spent programming (ps. that is the only account with host set as %)

Comment: I should also point out, that skip-grant-tables does not work.

Comment: Weird. In the perfect world it should work. I would double check the credential and make sure they're all match exactly.